# MSSQL Server is inaccessible from other domain users

Tags: windows-server-2003, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am unable to connect to other machines with the same domain and network. SQL Server 2008 is running, I can connect locally with MSSQL01\Administrator and password using Windows authentication.

Although I would like other servers also to be able to access it... but it fails with the following  error:

```
Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication.
```

And how come after renaming the hostname and following instructions at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143799.aspx, both MSSQL(old hostname) and MSSQL01 appear in sqlcmd -L.

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator>sqlcmd -L

Servers:
    MSSQL
    MSSQL01
```

Comment: Have a try using [SERVERNAME]\MSSQL01\Administrator

Answer (score 1):

You do not say how they are trying to access it, but there is almost certainly a method to provide an alternative username and password, and you would want to specify MSSQL01\Administrator (in that exact form, unless there is a box for a domain). You are probably trying to connect as the administrator on the foreign host, which of course, is a different user, and does not have permissions.

Comment: They are trying to access it via an installer. Veeam on BACKUP, and vCenter on VCENTER. How do I make this work? It worked fine with MSSQL2005 on another machine.

Answer (score 1):

`MSSQL01\Administrator` is not a domain account (if I'm reading things correctly), it is a machine local account.  You won't be able to use that account to authenticate to other domain machines, you'll need to use a domain account to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Check the `SQL server configuration manager>SQL server network configuration>Protocols...`. Make sure that TCP/IP is enabled. Hope this helps.